# Does a possessive nominalize an adjective in Indonesian?

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech, malay

- [image: “Sedihmu adalah sedihku juga / Sakitmu, sakitku, sakit kita manusia / Bahagiaku takkan lengkap tanpa bahagiamu / Bahagiakanlah kehidupan”]
- [Fletch’s song “**Lara**ku, **Pilu**mu”](https://youtu.be/kbdVxBvDY4w)

---

“Sedih,” “lara,” “pilu”….

Those are all adjectives, yet they’re being modified by possessives (“-ku,” “-mu,” “kita manusia,” et cetera.).

Does it mean that possessives nominalize adjectives in Indonesian?

Comment: Perhaps it means that parts of speech are not stable, and/or that pronoun clitics are not limited to nouns.